# Access Multiple SQL Connection

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, join

I have two queries in Access which are returning two tables like:
(The tables have both about 1000 lines)

```
SELECT 
    (select count(*) 
     from Table1 T2 
     where T1.Name=T2.Name and T1.Variable1 >= T2.Variable1) as Rank,
    T1.Name,
    T1.Variable1
FROM Table1 T1
```

Results:

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| Rank  |  Name   |  Variable1 |
+-------+---------+------------+
|    1  |  Tim    |  x         |
|    2  |  Tim    |  y         |
|    3  |  Tim    |  z         |
|    1  |  Susan  |  x         |
|    2  |  Susan  |  w         |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

Second query:

```
SELECT (select count(*) 
        from Table2 T2 
        where T1.Name=T2.Name and T1.Variable2 >= T2.Variable2) as Rank, 
T1.Name,T1.Variable2
FROM Table2 T1
```

Results:

```
+--------+---------+------------+
|  Ran   |  Name   |  Variable2 |
+--------+---------+------------+
|     1  |  Tim    |  a         |
|     2  |  Tim    |  b         |
|     3  |  Tim    |  c         |
|     1  |  Susan  |  a         |
|     2  |  Susan  |  c         |
+--------+---------+------------+
```

I want to link them:

```
Select distinct Table1.Name, Table1.Variable1, Table2.Variable2
from Table1, Table2
where Table1.Name=Table2.Name and Table1.Rank=Table2.Rank
```

Results:

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+
|     Rank  |  Name   |  Variable1  |  Variable2 |
+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+
|        1  |  Tim    |  x          |  a         |
|        2  |  Tim    |  y          |  b         |
|        3  |  Tim    |  z          |  c         |
|        1  |  Susan  |  x          |  a         |
|        2  |  Susan  |  w          |  b         |
+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

But that link isn't performing well in access.

I also tried to link them via "join" but the performance isnt getting better.

Comment: Please indent your code blocks by 4 spaces so that they get formatted properly.

Comment: Please specify what you mean with _isn't performing well in access._, and explain what you are asking exactly. Your sample data + query wouldn't return those results (rank 2 and 3 aren't present in Table2), please adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

These ranking queries are expensive (the subquery has to be executed for each row of the main table).

Stacking / cascading expensive queries in Access often performs badly.

Your best option is to change your 1st and 2nd query into "Create table" (`SELECT INTO`) queries, storing the results in intermediate tables.

E.g.

```
SELECT 
    (select count(*) 
     from Table1 T2 
     where T1.Name=T2.Name and T1.Variable1 >= T2.Variable1) as Rank,
    T1.Name,
    T1.Variable1
INTO Result1
FROM Table1 T1
```

Then use these tables (`Result1`, `Result2`) as input for the JOIN.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I will try that.